# CSS3 transition z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the website I've been working on: [Comotional - test site](http://test.comotional.com/)

I am using flipping cards within "Who we are" section and have problems with z-index. Whichever z-index and css combination I tried (even added additional divs on the back side), I can't fix the flipped content appearing below other cards. If you hover over these, you will see what happens and will see where the problems happens. Is there anyway to get this working via js?

Comment: its not possible to alter website's script so you should create a fiddle that act like the `who we are` to make it possible for others to test and debug the code

Comment: @UDB It's CSS, use the DevTools...

Answer (score 0):

It's limited by your container height, not the z-index. Set the height auto and find another way to set up the grid - perhaps making something like a row container along with a clear div while setting height to the front side of the card.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you have lots of nested elements so changing the `z-index` of a nested element does not make them appear above on the stack unless until you make the `z-index` of the parent container greater than other parent containers that are blocking the view.

you can use `hover` event to change/increase the `z-index` of parent container on mouse-in and default on mouse-out

[**link to justify what I am saying**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)